# Entity Framework update wizard only showing stored procedures in system folder

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

- I created a stored procedure in sql server called dbo.GetDrugSetHistory
- I tested the SP, works fine.
- I went into my .edmx file and right clicked, then clicked "update Model from Database..."
- I am unable to click the checkbox that says "Stored Procedures and Functions", the checkbox at the bottom that says "Import selected stored procedures and functions into the entity model" is greyed out and not selectable.
- I then click on the "Refresh" tab, and then click to expand "Stored Procedures and Functions", below this I see one schema "dbo", when I click to expand "dbo", I only get the dbo procedures listed in the "System Stored Procedures" folder (i.e. fn_diagramobjects, sp_alterdiagram, etc.)

Does anyone know why I cannot see my newly created stored procedure?  Is this a permissions issue?

here is a copy of the stored procedure, just in case...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDrugSetHistory] 
@ProfileID int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT distinct s.*
from Prescriptions p
LEFT JOIN Sets s ON p.SetID = s.SetID
where p.ProfileID = @ProfileID
END
```

Comment: Could still just be a refresh issue of sorts. Have you added other stored procedures before? If this the first sproc you have added to your model it could be a permission issue or perhaps you have not set a default database in your connection string and your sql server default setting is the master database which is out of the box default I believe.

Comment: the connection string in my app.config points to the correct "initial catalog".  the stored procedures that the edmx is seeing are coming from the dbo schema in the correct database.  How would I check permission issues?  It's able to see the tables fine, just not the stored procedures...

Answer (score 2):

OK, figured it out.  It was a SQL Server permissions issue.  Went into the user account properties and granted a bunch of permissions.  The stored procedures now appear.